# How to show error messages for min and max values of an input field with number type?

Tags: angularjs, angular-validation

How do I set/show error messages for min and max values that I set on an input field with number type using angular js.

```
<input type="number" min="0.1" max="30"/>
```

Answer (score 10):

*Please use below code to show error message for min and max value in number input type field using angularjs validation.*

For ng-maxlength and ng-minlength for Number input type field.

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="number" name="count" ng-model="count" max="30" min="0.1">
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.min">Count should be above 0.1.</span>
        <span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.max">Count should be below 30.</span>
    </span>
</form>
```

For maxlength and minlength for Text input type field.

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="username" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="15">
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.username.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="myForm.username.$error.minlength">Username should be minimum 5 character.</span>
        <span ng-show="myForm.username.$error.maxlength">Username should be maximum 15 character.</span>
    </span>
</form>
```

Comment: Can I use the same technique on minlength and maxlength?

Comment: @Harish - Maxlength and minlength should be used for text length, not for number type field. Use below code for maxlength and minlength for text type input field.

Answer (score 3):

You need to encapsulate the `input` inside the `form` and conditionally display the *error* messages:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = {};
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}

input {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
  <form novalidate name="myForm">
    <label for="model.data">Enter Data:</label>
    <input type="number" name="data" ng-model="model.data" min="0.1" max="30" />
    <div class="error" ng-show="myForm.data.$dirty && myForm.data.$error.min" ng-message="min">Unexpected minimum data</div>
    <div class="error" ng-show="myForm.data.$dirty && myForm.data.$error.max" ng-message="max">Unexpected maximum data</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple :

```
 <p class="help-block" ng-message="min || max">please enter in between 0.1 to 30.</p>
```

or

```
<p class="help-block" ng-message="min">Min 0.1 required</p>
<p class="help-block" ng-message="max">Max 30 Allowd</p>
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try it and let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `required` to input field.

here is SAMPLE CODE and fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/nc4n61bk/

```
<form>

<input type="number" min="0.1" max="30" required/> 
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = {};
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}

input {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
  <form novalidate name="myForm">
    <label for="model.data">Enter Data:</label>
    <input type="number" name="data" ng-model="model.data" min="0.1" max="30" />
    <div class="error" ng-show="myForm.data.$dirty && myForm.data.$error.min" ng-message="min">Unexpected minimum data</div>
    <div class="error" ng-show="myForm.data.$dirty && myForm.data.$error.max" ng-message="max">Unexpected maximum data</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Providing code without explanation is generally considered low quality. Could you provide some explanation as to why your answer works?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.valueError{
   color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
   padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
 <form novalidate name="myForm">
<div class="form-field required-field">
<label for="field-value">Value</label>
<input type="number" id="field-value" name="valueInput" class="small form-control input-md ng-valid ng-dirty" ng-model="value" min="5" placeholder="Value"/>
<div class="valueError" ng-show="form.value.$dirty && form.value.$error.min "> Value must be atleast 5min</div>
</div>
 </form>
</div>
```